# Return HttpStatus code in a method returns Task<List<T>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-codes

How can I return different types of HttpStatus codes in a method which returns a list?
If the method hits `try` block it should return 200(Automatically it happens since it is a successful response). Need to return 404 if it hits the `catch` block.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{customerId}")]
public async Task<List<CategoryEntity>> GetCategoryByCustomerId(Guid customerId)
{
    try
    {
         List<CategoryEntity> categoryEntities = _categoryRepository.GetAllCategoriesByCustomerId(customerId);
         return categoryEntities;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
         return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case you can return strict type i.e. List<CategoryEntity> which can be either null or some value. You need to return IActionResult. then return httpresponse result with some content.

Comment: You may consider creating a new ResponseModel with properties `Status Code` and `Entity`. You should not return 404 status which indicates the url resource is not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your method to produce specific HTTP status codes, your method should return an `IActionResult`. The `ActionResult` types are representative of HTTP status codes ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iactionresult-type)).

For your method, you would return an `OkResult` inside of your try block to have the method respond with an HTTP 200 and a `NotFoundResult` inside of your catch for it to respond with an HTTP 404.

You can pass the data that you want to send back to the client (i.e. your `List<T>`) to `OkResults`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I keep running into this and even though James basically gave the answer, it takes me a moment too long to remember the obvious: just add ActionResult into your Return type cascade, like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<CategoryEntity>>> GetCategoryByCustomerId(...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{customerId}")]
public async Task<List<CategoryEntity>> GetCategoryByCustomerId(Guid customerId)
{
    try
    {
        List<CategoryEntity> categoryEntities = _categoryRepository.GetAllCategoriesByCustomerId(customerId);
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return categoryEntities;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return null;
    }
}
```